# Параметр типа boolean для запуска java программы

Tags: java, linux, windows, bat, sh

Допустим есть [программа](https://github.com/PaperMC/Paperclip/blob/97ec86ee3e1c742929be015c2beab14bb8404d89/java8/src/main/java/com/destroystokyo/paperclip/Paperclip.java#L138). При определенном параметре в строке запуска её поведение изменится. Как правильно задать аргумент запуска данной программы в bat файле, чтобы она "поняла" требуемый параметр *paperclip.patchonly*?

Comment: `-Dpaperclip.patchonly=true` укажите при запуске программы

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189914/setting-system-property

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Спасибо, помогло.